# Accessing AsyncStorage react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Hello I am new to react Native and I would like to access the user id that was stored to  react Native storage  so that I can pass it to the WebSocket connection but it is not returning the id

**here is my sample code**

```
    import { io } from "socket.io-client/dist/socket.io";
    import env from "../utils/env";
    import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

    const getUserData = async () => {
      try {
         const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("UserData");
            if (value !== null) {
      return value;
    }
  } catch (e) {
    // remove error
  }

  console.log("Done.");
};

getUserData().then((res) => {
  let response = JSON.parse(res);
  console.log(response._id);
});

let socket = io(`${env.DEV_SERVER_URL}`, {
  transports: ["websocket"],
  query: `mobileId=${getUserData().then((res) =>{
      let response = JSON.parse(res);
      return response._id
  })}`,
});

export default socket;
```

Comment: Can share code snippet on how you're saving data in Async Storage

Answer (score 0):

```
const storeData = async (data) =>{
await AsyncStorage.setItem('UserData', JSON.stringify(UserData));
}
```

try this to store your data you might have forgot to stringify your object before storing it

Comment: The data was already stored I want to retrieve it